# What does "CELLO" mean in "350G/750G CELLO"

Tags: pastry

what does "CELLO" mean in "KUCHENMEISTER STOLLEN 350G/750G CELLO" in the attached image? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture of the item?  It’s possible that it means ‘cellophane’ (a type of plastic wrapping) if it’s individually wrapped items, but usually stolen is a single loaf/cake.

Comment: You’ve asked a couple of questions like this. Have you considered looking at the product itself to identify it? Or asking an employee? They would be better-placed to answer than we would; there’s no standards for this stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I only managed to take a photo of the sign; it was crowded because of the holiday season. I have asked similar questions in person in the past. Most of the time they'll say they don't know, especially if they are part- time employees. If I insist in getting an answer, some would give me "the look"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, "CELLO" refers to the packaging material used for the Kuchenmeister stollen product. It indicates that the stollen, available in 350 grams or 750 grams, is packaged or wrapped in cellophane (often abbreviated as "CELLO"), a transparent, thin, and flexible material made from cellulose. This material helps in preserving and protecting the product from external elements while allowing consumers to see the contents inside.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations! Happy holidays ~